# bootstrap datatable with bootstrap switch not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am working on small project that include datatable and bootstrap switch in the table column the switch is working fine

[Working switch on Admin confirm column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLE4u.png)

When clicking on the '+' icon it open a modal and switch not working on the modal window.

[Switch not working on modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOZZo.png)

i am using this example of datatable `https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html`

can anyone help me to fix this issue

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
$('#datatables').DataTable( {
"processing": true,
 "serverSide": true,
 "ajax": "member-process-view-all.php",
"aaSorting":[[0, "desc"]],
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
 $('.BSswitch').bootstrapSwitch();
},
    responsive: {
        details: {
            display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal( {
                header: function ( row ) {
                    var data = row.data();
                    return 'Details for '+data[2]+' '+data[3];                         
                }
            } ),
            renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll( {
                tableClass: 'table'
            } )
        }
    }
} );
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I have added the script